# Want to delete all rows of records containing null values in DolphinDB

Tags: sql-delete, dolphindb

I have a table where a record may contain null values in one or more columns. I want to delete these records as long as it contains a null value. I'm wondering if there is any suggested way to do that in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

Try DolphinDB function `rowAnd` to specify the output conditions.

The following script is for your reference. It outputs rows of data only when the columns meet the set conditions (delete the records if NULL contained):

```
sym = take(`a`b`c, 110)
id = 1..100 join take(int(),10)
id2 =  take(int(),10) join 1..100
t = table(sym, id,id2)

t[each(isValid, t.values()).rowAnd()]
```

The output can be found in the screenshot:

[image]